# Need help to Install Apache::Registry on windows machine

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

Am trying to install Apache::Registry on my windows machine. But, i was not able to do that. Because, it is asking for the Apache.exe location. When i give it the full `path("C:\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe")`, then it is throughing the following error. Please help me to overcome this issue.

```
cpan> install Apache::Registry
Running install for module 'Apache::Registry'
Running make for G/GO/GOZER/mod_perl-1.31.tar.gz
Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\mod_perl-1.31-Pn_
8fL
Has already been made
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe t/TEST.win32 0
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Please supply the full path to Apache.exe:
```

Thanks in advance.

-Anji

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question, you might have better luck asking something like this over at [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) on the stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[`Apache::Registry` is from mod_perl v1](http://p3rl.org/Apache%3a%3aRegistry) for Apache httpd v1. You want [`ModPerl::Registry` from mod_perl v2](http://p3rl.org/ModPerl%3a%3aRegistry) for your Apache httpd v2.

You can avoid building from source, see the [mod_perl 2.0 Win32 Installation Instructions](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html#PPM_Packages).